# I can't tell if monerod is mining. Log says "idle percentage is 63%, miner percentage is 38%"

Tags: monerod, mining

I want to turn mining *off*, but the log is still reporting a message that seems to imply mining is on:

```
idle percentage is 63%, miner percentage is 38%,
```

The .exe was executed with a --mining-threads 0 option. The CPU use is hovering around 40% continuously. How can I tell if mining is actually turned off?

Edit:

In my logs from this morning I see the following...

```
 2018-12-20 06:08:49.580    [P2P1]  INFO    net.p2p.msg src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:764 [80.172.224.92:51394 INC] Received NOTIFY_NEW_TRANSACTIONS (1 txes)
2018-12-20 06:08:49.752 [miner 0]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [0]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.752 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p.msg src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:764 [188.162.145.81:33525 INC] Received NOTIFY_NEW_TRANSACTIONS (1 txes)
2018-12-20 06:08:49.768 [miner 1]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [1]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.768 [miner 2]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [2]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.768 [miner 4]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [4]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.815 [miner 3]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [3]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.815 [miner 5]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [5]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.815 [miner 6]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [6]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.861 [miner 7]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:510  Miner thread stopped [7]
2018-12-20 06:08:49.861 [RPC0]  INFO    miner   src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:381  Mining has been stopped, 8 finished
2018-12-20 06:08:49.877 [P2P1]  INFO    net.p2p.msg src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:764 [31.48.31.26:61800 INC] Received NOTIFY_NEW_TRANSACTIONS (1 txes)
2018-12-20 06:08:50.143 [RPC0]  INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:576  [check_and_resize_for_batch] checking DB size
2018-12-20 06:08:50.143 [RPC0]  INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:544  DB map size:     82618601472
2018-12-20 06:08:50.143 [RPC0]  INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:545  Space used:      70941216768
2018-12-20 06:08:50.143 [RPC0]  INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:546  Space remaining: 11677384704
2018-12-20 06:08:50.143 [RPC0]  INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:547  Size threshold:  0
2018-12-20 06:08:50.143 [RPC0]  INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:549  Percent used: 0.8587  Percent threshold: 0.9000
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 0]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [0]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 1]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [1]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 2]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [2]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 3]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [3]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [RPC0]  WARN    miner   src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:325  Mining has started with 8 threads, good luck!
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 5]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [5]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [RPC0]  WARN    miner   src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:330  Background mining controller thread started
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [RPC0]  INFO    miner   src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:335  Ignoring battery
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 6]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [6]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 4]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [4]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.158 [miner 7]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:441  Miner thread was started [7]
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 5]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 4]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 3]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 0]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 7]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 1]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [miner 6]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:460  background mining is enabled, but not started, waiting until start triggers
2018-12-20 06:08:50.268 [P2P1]  INFO    net.p2p.msg src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:764 [99.229.235.60:37364 INC] Received NOTIFY_NEW_TRANSACTIONS (1 txes)
```

However I never issued any commands to the monerod process. Why would mining stop (I never even started it) and then begin again?

Comment: Which OS and which miner software? And maybe add more details you think might be relevant.

Comment: Using windows, monero v13.0.4.
 I added logs from this morning. Mining was running, stopped, then started again. Has someone taken control of my node? I have not issued any commands to it.

Comment: Fuck... RPC bind was enabled. Does that mean someone else could have issued mining commands and was telling my node to solo mine for someone else's wallet? Is that even possible?

Comment: If you open up your RPC interface to the world, yes, someone remotely can issue a `start_mining` command.

Comment: Yep that's definitely what happened. FML. Oh well. This node isn't on a powerful machine, but I've still been paying for the electricity for at least a week.

Note to self, disable RPC.

Comment: You can also use --restricted-rpc, which is designed for those RPC connections open to third parties. Among other things, mining control will be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing log messages like posted, mining is running. You can stop mining by simply typing `stop_mining` in the monerod window (if running interactively) or by running `monerod stop_mining` in a terminal if it's running detached.

Of course, you can start the daemon without specifying any of the mining parameters (such as `--start-mining`) and it won't even start mining in the first place.

Comment: I added the logs from this morning. Mining was running, stopped, then started again. Not sure how/why.